# Excel calculations across many tabs with many formulas and named ranges

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, named-ranges

I have a *massive* Excel Workbook and I am having problems with some of the formula calculations that make use of custom VBA functions and Named Ranges.

The workflow for the workbook is a bunch of calculations on Tab 1, that then filter to calculations on Tab 2, that then filter to calculations on Tab 3... so on and so forth. As previously stated, this workbook is *massive* and I actually need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> (force recalculate entire workbook) to make 99% of the data work calculate fully after changes are made. However, one set of calculations (modeled in the linked workbook) do not behave like everything else.

In the workbook ([Testing Workbook found here](http://www.filedropper.com/testbook_1)), The data flows like so:

1. "Calculations" tab creates the total row 23
2. Those values go to "CountryLevelOutput" tab for aggregation later
3. Those values then go to "ZoneLevelOutput" to be rolled up into "Zones" (zones defined in the "Countries" tab)
4. Those values then go to the "Rollups" tab for a readable format.

> Note: I cannot get rid of any of these intermediary steps due to their use in other tabs not relevant to this issue.

All the values should look good from the get-go in the file for download. If you execute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> on the "Rollups" tab, you will see that the values dissappear (or at least I hope so! It does on my two computers with Excel 2010...). Navigate back to the "Calculations" tab and the values in row 23 **will all be 0 even though they previously were not**. Execute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> on the "Calculations" tab and all will be well again.

How come <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd>, when executed from the "Rollups" tab, totally screws with the calculation flow? I am curious if it has something to do with the VBA or Named Ranges?

Please note: the "work around" for executing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> only on the "Calculations" tab does not work for the real workbook. In the real workbook, the issue I have is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> on "Calculations" zeroes-out 50% of "Rollup", while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F9</kbd> on "Rollup" zeroes-out just this single instance on the "Calculations".

Comment: I think it's just too complicated for Excel, it just can't just decide which is the right order to calculate your workbook, so order of calculation will depend on activesheet instead of dependency of formulae. Have you tried to create a macro to initiate recalculation (activate and recalculate the sheets one by one according to the logical order). (Having such a complex model I'd consider to move it to Access.)

Comment: A fix I have stumbled upon is to change the VBA logic from using --Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT((" & Buckets(i + 1).Address & "=""x"") * RangeHasCountry(Countries, Country_Columns) * " & Values.Address & ")")--, to manually iterating through each cell and counting. It is very rudimentary logic and more time intensive, but at least Excel does not calculate oddly. Due to this fix, I am agree that this is awkwardness in Excel's order of calculations. As for Access: thanks for the suggestion, but I am unable to change the medium of this project.